# Sync Office 365 (Exchange) calendar with Android

Tags: exchange, nexus-4, active-sync

I have a Nexus 4 and an Office 365 account. I cannot setup sync between Office 365 exchange server and the Android builtin Exchange account manager (called "corporate" in Android settings).

What happens is that Android settings seems to approve my input of Exchange information from Office 365 including username, password and server host, but then no sync of Email, Calendar, Contacts etc. takes place.

I've tried 3rd party apps such as MailDroid, Touchdown, RoadSync and RemoSync work. Of these, only Maildroid is great but doesn't have calendar support. Touchdown and the others are very clunky, and I've no particular desire to try anything else unless someone can make a strong recommendation.

What I'd really like to do is use the native Google calendar app with my Office 365 account. Is anyone able to help me get that working?